# How can I load a model after using {{link-to}} with a model passed in already

Tags: ember.js

In Ember 2.5.

```
{{#each model.vehicletypes as |vt|}}
    <tr>
        ...
        <td class="text-center text-success">{{#link-to "admin.vehicletypes.edit" vt}}<i class="material-icons">create</i>{{/link-to}}</td>
        <td class="text-center text-danger"><i class="material-icons" {{action "delete" vt}}>delete</i></td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

When clicking the {{link-to}} to edit a vehicle type, it passes model.vehicletypes. Once I am on the edit page, I need to get another model to populate a list. But navigating with a model passed in already means that no other model will be requested.

How can I request another model in the edit page?

Comment: Take your time and read the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/links/) this has already been covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an object, the model hook won't fire. Instead, pass `vt.id` and use that id to make the requests in the edit.js route.